# How to convert a web page that using a Master page to one without a Master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I have a web page no.1 that uses a Master page and now I want to have it displayed by a link on another page no.2 which also uses the same Master page. I want to take no.1 out of the Master page. Do I have to create a new web page for that or can I change the already existing page, if so how? What would be the easiest and most efficient way? Thank you.

Comment: do you mean to display page2 as an iframe?

Comment: I don't understand very well. You want a link in the PAGE2 to the PAGE1? If it is the case the common master page is not a problem I think.

Comment: what exactly you want to do?

Comment: The link is in a menu on the master page and the taget is an iframe in page2. I want page1 to be displayed on page2 with the master page including the menu thru page2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in this case the easiest thing will be to create a blank master page without your links and navigation. In the second page in initialization phase you can set the master page as

```
void Page_PreInit(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
this.MasterPageFile = "~/NewMaster.master";
}
```

since newmaster is blank you wont get any links and other junks.
just create your logic in preinit event to when to change the master(i.e when the page is in i frame you can call it via querystring) and this querystring can be used to check it is in iframe or not. if it is in iframe you can set the blank master page else leave it.

Comment: Exelent clean and simple! Thank you! One thing more how do I check if it's in iframe or not?

Comment: when ever you are calling the page in iframe just append a querystring, and check for this querystring in the page init and do accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to make page no.1 so it no longer uses the MasterPage, do the following to page no.1:

- Remove the `MasterPageFile` attribute from its `<@ Page ...>` directive.
- Remove possible (optional) `<%@ MasterType ... %>` directive.
- Remove any `<asp:Content></asp:content>` tags (but maybe not their, er, contents).
- Add a `<!DOCTYPE html>` tag
- Add `<html>`, `<body>` and `<form runat="server">` tags